# How to assign the output of a command to a variable while checking if the command was successful?

Tags: bash, shell, if-statement

I'm going to try my best to explain the question. Please don't hesitate to ask for clarification if needed.

Ultimately, I want

1. to assign the output of a command to a variable while
2. maintaining the possibility to check if the command was successful or not.

In the following code, `ls` is only an example. The command I'm going to use is different.

For the first part, normally, I would do something like this:

```
{
  ls nonexistingfolder
} && {
  echo "fine"
} || {
  echo "error"
}
```

However, above code doesn't work, when I'm using `export` to save the output to a variable:

```
{
  export MESSAGE=$(ls nonexistingfolder)
} && {
  echo "fine"
} || {
  echo "error"
}
```

Above code will always print `fine`.

I tried something with an `if` statement:

```
export MESSAGE=$(ls notexistingfolder)
if [ -z "$MESSAGE" ] ; then echo "error" ; else echo "fine" ; fi
```

But above code won't work when the command succeeds without output (for example if `ls` lists an empty folder):

```
export MESSAGE=$(ls emptyfolder)
if [ -z "$MESSAGE" ] ; then echo "error" ; else echo "fine" ; fi
```

Above code falsely prints `error`.

So I thought about defining an "error value" for `$MESSAGE`:

```
export MESSAGE=$(ls notexistingfolder || echo "error")
if [ "$MESSAGE" = "error" ] ; then echo "error" ; else echo "fine" ; fi
```

Above code prints `error` as it should.

```
export MESSAGE=$(ls emptyfolder || echo "error")
if [ "$MESSAGE" = "error" ] ; then echo "error" ; else echo "fine" ; fi
```

Above code prints `fine` as it should.

However, there is the low possibility that the command will succeed and return a string which matches my "error value" exactly (for example if `ls` lists a folder which contains a folder called `error`):

```
export MESSAGE=$(ls folderwitherrorfolder || echo "error")
if [ "$MESSAGE" = "error" ] ; then echo "error" ; else echo "fine" ; fi
```

Above code will falsely print `error`.

What can I do? Thank you! :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just

```
MESSAGE=$(ls ...)
if [[ $? -eq 0 ]]; then
  success
else
  failure
fi
export MESSAGE
```

Points:

1. `var=$(foo ...)`: the assignment would not change `$?` so `$?` is still the foo's exit code.
2. `export` itself is a command so `export var=$(foo ...)`'s exit code would overwrite foo's exit code.

There ARE scenarios (syntax errors; assigning to readonly vars; ...) where `var=value` may change `$?` and `export` may fail. Examples:

```
[STEP 101] $ true
[STEP 102] $ 
[STEP 103] $ var=${:}
bash: ${:}: bad substitution
[STEP 104] $ echo $?
1
[STEP 105] $ export var=${:}
bash: var=${:}: bad substitution
[STEP 106] $ echo $?
1
[STEP 107] $
```

Comment: you can even write `if MESSAGE=$(ls ...); then ...` or `MESSAGE=$(ls ...) && ... || ...`

Answer (score 3):

`export` is usually successful, and you are evaluating the status of that command.  Just do:

```
MESSAGE=$(ls nonexistingfolder) && echo "fine" || echo "error"
export MESSAGE
```

Note that the 'echo error' is probably redundant, since ls is going to generate a decent error message.  And the 'echo fine' is also redundant and in violation of the typical unix philosophy to "succeed quietly and fail loudly", but YMMV.

Comment: @Inian.  IMO, no.  What should be suppressed is both of the `echo` statements.

Comment: @emmi474 yes. [ShellCheck](http://shellcheck.net) automatically points [this](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2155) out in your script.

Comment: @emmi474 Almost.  `export MESSAGE=$(cmd)` will always exit with the exit status of `export`.  That is *usually* 0, and indeed *possibly* always 0, but perhaps not.  I can imagine a scenario where `export` requires the shell to allocate memory, and perhaps is unable to.  Rather than trying to imagine all failure scenarios and convince yourself they can never happen, it's better to assume that `export` may fail.